# Getting Scala 2.10 annotation values at runtime

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations

So I have a documentation annotation that looks like this:

```scala
case class DocProp(name: String = "", dataType: Class[_] = classOf[Object])
```

The idea is that by default we'll introspect the field and look at the ID and return type, but in some cases that needs overriding.

I want to put it on the fields of my model case classes, so I redeclare it as a `type` with `@field`:

```scala
type DocProperty = DocProp @field
```

And then use it in the following different scenarios:

```scala
case class MyModel(
    // 1. use reflection to inspect the property
    @DocProperty
    prop1: Int,

    // 2. override the name
    @DocProperty(name = "myProp")
    prop2: String,

    // 3. override the return type
    @DocProperty(dataType = classOf[String])
    prop3: Option[String],

    // 4. override everything
    @DocProperty("myOtherProp", classOf[Number])
    prop4: Float,

    // 5. don't document this one at all
    hiddenProp: String
)
```

I've finally managed to dig through layers of `runtimeMirrors` and whatnot to get down to the `Symbols` for the values and their associated annotations, and dig out just the `DocProp` annotations:

```scala
// val mc = classOf[MyModel] // passed in
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(mc.getClassLoader)
val members = mirror.classSymbol(mc).asType.typeSignature.members

val allProps = (for (m <- members) yield {
  val a8ns = m.annotations
  val a8n = a8ns.find(a => a.tpe <:< ru.typeOf[DocProp])
  a8n match {
    case Some(found) => Some((m, found))
    case _ => None
  }
}).flatten
```

This gets me an iterable of `(Symbol, Annotation)` for just the annotated properties (I still need the Symbols for the reflective cases).

But I'm now deep in a thicket of `reflect.runtime.universe.Trees`, and it's not obvious to me how to get out. How do I get from

```scala
reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = classOf[java.lang.Number]
```

to an actual `Class[Number]` value? How do I get from

```scala
reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = doc.this.DocProp.<init>$default$1
```

to the empty string, or even to `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far there's no easy way of achieving that. Utilizing `ToolBox.eval` is the workaround that comes to mind. There's also a similar issue in our JIRA that talks about getting values of Java annotations: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6423.

Comment: For future readers: I ended up using Java annotations and a mix of Java and Scala reflection. It wasn't pretty, but it worked.

Comment: can you share an example?